# Relation between irreducible representations and eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, group-representations, eigenvalue

When in quantum mechanics the Hamiltonian possesses some symmetry, then knowing the irreducible representations of the group to which the symmetry belongs gives information about the eigenstates. As far as I understand each irrep leads to a quantum number and the dimension of the irrep equals the degeneracy. But how does that work exactly?

For example, say we have a two dimensional potential well that belongs to the finite group $D_3$ (for example an equilateral triangle). We know that $D_3$ had 3 irreps: the 1-dimensional trivial irrep, another 1-dimensional irrep, and a 2-dimensional irrep. Does this mean the eigenstates are defined by 3 quantum numbers and that the degeneracy in two of them is 1 while the third quantum number has a degeneracy of 2?

Comment: This is how I understand what is written in paragraph 5.3 of Jones' Groups, representations and physics. If it's right, I would really like to know how to show this in more detail. But what I'm saying feels wrong to me. I am very thankful for any ideas and suggestions!